# Find maximum value in a range of strings

Tags: excel, vba, increment

I have a spreadsheet with  number of different sheets.  Each sheet has a column with unique ID which is made up as follows:  AD-S001, AD-S002, AD-S003 etc.  The next sheet's unique ID could be AD-M001, AD-M002 etc.

I am pretty new to VBA in excel and am trying to write some code to create a new record, incrementing the unique ID.  The unique ID's are sometimes not sorted so I need to find the largest in the range and then increment it by 1.

I have the other code already, just trying to add the bit that finds the largest value in the range of strings and increments it by 1.

Grateful if someone could assist me in how best to write this sub-routine.

Thanks

Comment: You need to split string into parts and get correct integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the next function, please:

```
Function newID(sh As Worksheet) As String
 Dim lastR As Long, strID As String, arr As Variant, i As Long

 lastR = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arr = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR).Value
 
 strID = left(sh.Range("A2").Value, 4)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i, 1) = CLng(Right(arr(i, 1), 3))
 Next i
 newID = strID & Format(WorksheetFunction.Max(arr) + 1, "000")
End Function
```

It can be called/used in this way:

```
Sub testNewID()
   Dim sh As Worksheet
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary worksheet
   MsgBox newID(sh)
 End Sub
```

Comment: @Sean: Glad I could help! But, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... :)

Answer (score 0):

A non-VBA alternative, see if it is acceptable.

Set the format for the column as below

`"AD-S"000`

And then you can simply use a MAX formula to get the maximum value in preceding cells. Assuming first numbered cell is A2, formula in cell A3 would be:

`=MAX($A$2:A2)+1`

which can then be copied down as much needed.